# How to dynamically add change event to an external dropdownlist component in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to add a change event to an external dropdownlist component (which is being used in other components) that's been referenced in my current component. However, due to some reason it's throwing me an error as below: 
Cannot read property '__zone_symbol__addEventListener' of undefined. Below is the sample code for your reference.

External component code --

city.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Country" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">
        {{ country.name }}
    </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

city.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-citylist',
  templateUrl: './citylist.component.html'
})
export class CitylistComponent implements OnInit {

  cities : City[];  

  constructor(private citylistService : CitylistService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getCities();    
  }

  getCities() : void{    
     this.cityListService.getCities().subscribe(resultArray => this.cities = 
     resultArray,
     error => console.log("Error :: " + error));
  }
}
```

Current component code:

temp.html

```
<app-citylist #Citylist (ngModelChange)="onVenueChange(selectedCity)" 
    formControlName="selectedCity" name="selectedCity" required 
    ngDefaultControl></app-citylist>
```

temp.component.ts

```
export class tempComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.renderer.listen(this.city1.nativeElement, 'change',(evt)=>{
      alert("It has been clicked");
  }); 
 }
 @ViewChild('Citylist') city1;

 onVenueChange(venueId, formGroup: NgForm ){
      alert("This is test");       
 }
}
```

Am I following the right approach ? Can someone please advise ?

Comment: Can someone please respond to my question ?

Comment: @J.D. I have made the changes as suggested but still I am getting undefined error. Am I following the correct approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see such imperfections in this approach:

1. You want to set change event handler for angular testComponent. But even with usual way you should have Output with name 'change' defined in it to do that.
2. You try to add handler to native element, but you should do that for angular component itself.
3. Actual change event is produced by child component mat-select, so you should put change event handler there and emit value on higher level.

Your approach will not work in the way it is done now

Comment: Thanks I have followed your instructions and created a sample below https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8mzabs-yw4q6c?file=app/select-overview-example.css

Comment: @but for me worked after changing event in temp.component.html from (change) to (selectionChange)